# How to disable manual seeking on Google Actions/Assistant Conversations - Media response?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm already able to play music with @assistant/conversation by using this:

```
conv.add(new Media({
        mediaObjects: [{
        name: 'Trance Track 1',
        description: 'Media description',
        url: 'https://my-url.de/Trance1.mp3',
        image: {
          large: new Image({
            url: 'https://somewhere/whateverimage.jpg',
            alt: 'my image here'
          })
        }
    }],
        mediaType: MediaType.Audio,
        optionalMediaControls: [OptionalMediaControl.Paused, OptionalMediaControl.Stopped],
        startOffset: '0s'
    }));
```

But the user is able to seek forward/backward. How can I disable this?

TuneIn already has this. I could not find anything in the docs: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this issue can be found on the corresponding GitHub issue: https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-nodejs/issues/17

In summary:

> Unfortunately, the Media response API does not support the features requested (i.e. disable seeking, prevent skip track, skip track w/ complex rule set, etc.).
>
> To get a full overview on what features Media response provides, as well as it's limitations, please refer to our documentation:
> https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media
>
> Feature request tickets have been filed internally for [these features].